# Using liquibase mongodb extension with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, migration, liquibase

Trying to use liquibase-mongodb extension with Spring Boot, but running a migration has no effect on my database.

Added liquibase-core, liquibase-mongodb extension and ongo-java-driver as dependencies in a pom file.

Here is my changelog file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.0.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

<changeSet id="first" author="andrei">
    <ext:createCollection collectionName="myCollection">
        <ext:options>
            {
            validator: {
            $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            required: ["name", "address"],
            properties: {
            name: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "The Name"
            },
            address: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "The Address"
            }
            }
            }
            },
            validationAction: "warn",
            validationLevel: "strict"
            }
        </ext:options>
    </ext:createCollection>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I try to inject bean SpringLiquibase but it requires from me a DataSource, which is an interface, and mongo extension for liquidbase doesn't provide an implementation of this interface.

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    MongoLiquibaseDatabase db = new MongoLiquibaseDatabase();
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml");
    //How to do this?
    // liquibase.setDataSource();
    liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
    return liquibase;
}
```

Does anyone have a working example of the liquidbase mongodb extension with Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest route is probably to use `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource` and `liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoClientDriver`.

The MongoClientDriver is part of the liquibase-mongodb extension and adapts a MongoClient to the `java.sql.Driver` interface as Liquibase needs it.

That should allow you to create the SimpleDriverDataSource and pass it to liquibase like:

```
SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource(new MongoClientDriver(), YOUR_URL, YOUR_USERNAME, YOUR_PASSWORD);
liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Comment: Do you have a working example of this?  I'm getting a "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException Cannot initiate a SQL Connection for a NoSql DB".  Code is:
    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase springLiquibase(){
        SimpleDriverDataSource simpleDriverDataSource =  new SimpleDriverDataSource(new MongoClientDriver(),
                "mongodb://localhost:27017/appdb",
                NULL,
                NULL
        );
        SpringLiquibase springLiquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        springLiquibase.setDataSource(simpleDriverDataSource);
        return springLiquibase;
 }

Comment: I am also facing the same issue i.e. Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot initiate a SQL Connection for a NoSql DB. Is it possible to share POM used? Perhaps it is the dependencies which is conflicting in my case, given provided solution has been accepted.